# HelloWorld C++: mysterious request to access desktop folder

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, permissions, desktop

Following instructions here, I built and executed the following code under Mac OS 11.6 and VS code 1.61.2. Code unmodified from
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When it executes, Mac OS pops up with the following unexpected question:
"helloworld wants permission to access files on the desktop." When denied, the program exited without complaint and without output. When executed directly from the command line, helloworld prints the expected output and does not show the strange behavior.

What the heck? I touched no files! Is my C++ library corrupted with malware? Has anyone else seen this odd behavior?

I finally said yes and it quit asking. Should I change my mind? And where would I go to do so?

Comment: not a macos user, but maybe this helps: ["<program>" would to access your files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394972/program-would-like-to-access-files-in-your-documents-folder-message-with-v) - [related github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5282)

Comment: is the program stored on your desktop by any chance?

Comment: Before going further, use a virus scanner hopefully to rule that out. Takes just a minute for peace of mind. Then, as @AlanBirtles suggests, investigate where it is running - also investigate where your VScode is installed. My guess is that VSCode is inserting something "convenient" into your exe.

Comment: @RMiller vs code is a glorified text editor, it wont be doing anything to the executable

Comment: i think MacOS just doesnt like "using namespace std;".

Comment: <s>Please contact Apple support</s>

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Alan Birtles, moving its grandparent folder off the desktop to another location solved the message and more.

Comment: I'm still looking for a better answer than this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the codes in application folder it will not ask again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).