# Why my output of C code didn't print out in my terminal on macbook?

Tags: c

Today I just start learning C language. I try to run my code, but I don't know where my output is?. I follow every step in youtube that I watch, and it still the same.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Helo");
}
```

and after I try to run, there is some notification show on my desktop

this is notification:

[image]

How do I fix this, and where can I see my output?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`"<program>" would like to access files in your Documents folder\` message with VS Code and macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394972/program-would-like-to-access-files-in-your-documents-folder-message-with-v)

Comment: @Nathan., My english is not good, so I don't understand clearly with the link that you give me. Now, I can fix this with another way. by the wat, Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use VS code for coding the C code. So, now I know how to fix it.

1. Go to Extensions.
2. Search for "code runner" you will see .run profile, and then install it.
3. Go to setting in VS code and search for "code runner run in terminal", you will see "Code-runner: Run in Terminal", and then tick in the box that say "Whether to run code in Intergrated Terminal.".
4. Restart VS code.
5. You can run C code and C++ code in VS code now.

Thanks. (07 August, 2023)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the ok button so that the program (compiler) can create the executable file (.exe) file on your disk drive.
This .exe file will then be run by the terminal to output you the expected result.

Comment: ., Thanks!, I find the output now.